# Не работает код с модулем Turtle

Tags: python, turtle

Хочу сделать чтобы черепаха рисовала имитированный график акций

```
import turtle
import random
import time

pockey = turtle.Turtle()
pockey.shape('turtle')
pockey.penup()
pockey.setpos(-300, 0)
pockey.pendown()

x = False
while True:
    i = random.randint(0, 1)
    if i == 0 and x != True:
        pockey.right(45)
        pockey.forward(20)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        x = True
    elif i == 1 and x != True:
        pockey.left(45)
        pockey.forward(20)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        x = True
    else:
        pockey.forward(20)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        x = False
    
turtle.mainloop()
```

черепашка появляется и идет в рандомном направлении вверх или вниз на 45
градусов. если она уже во второй раз поворачивает в одну и ту же сторону то она
иди ровно вправо.

Comment: Как же не работает, если ты сам написал, что работает?

Comment: @Эникейщик это псевдокод типо, извините то что не уточнил этот момент